# In Search/Spotlight, can you exclude files within $HOME/Library?

Tags: spotlight, search, path, library, smart-folders

I am trying to make some Smart Folders to compensate for the woefully useless **Recents** folder but I am having some problems trying to filter out things I don't want to appear.

One of them is excluding anything that is anywhere within the `$HOME/Library` directory or some approximation of that. I looked into the additional file attributes that are usable as search criteria that can be used in making a Smart Folder (in other words, the list that comes up when you click "other" in the search criteria menu) for things like "path", "has parent directory", or anything similar which would indicate the file/folder is buried in `$HOME/Library` somewhere. "Name" only pertains to actual file name and "Document Container" only pertains to the immediate parent directory. I cannot find any attribute whatsoever which might have the full path shown.

Is there a work-around for this, or perhaps, is there a file attribute that has this info that I am simply not seeing that is available?

Anyone know iff

Comment: Can you use [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/173488/88313) to exclude a folder from Spotlight?

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of actually excluding $HOME/Library from the Spotlight index altogether. That would certainly do the job but that does come at the cost of never being able to use Finder search within $HOME/Library for any reason. I suppose I could `locate` for such things on the CLI. Hmm... 

Anyway, thanks for that suggestion- worth considering.

Comment: Why do you find recents folder so useless?

Comment: For me, neither Spotlight nor Smart Folders show results of files in the user Library. I don't have anything configured to be excluded.

Answer (score 2):

Spotlight does not index file paths as a property of a file. Thus you can't search for files by path. You also can't ask it to find or exclude files by their parent folder.

You thus need to resort to a two-step process:

1. Run a search against the Spotlight index. You can do so at the
   command line using the `mdfind` command Filter the results to hide
   those in your Library folder.
2. You could use the  `grep` command. Alternatively, you can paste the results from mdfind in a spreadsheet and use that to [filter the list](https://support.apple.com/guide/numbers/filter-data-tan28bd63a8a/mac).

You can get the results you want using the [HoudahSpot](https://www.houdah.com/houdahSpot/) application. This has the option to specify more than one search location and to exclude locations. HoudahSpot also has an option to filter search results by path. Here you can apply regular expressions.

HoudahSpot can save searches as Finder "Smart Folders".  Since the feature you are after is not supported by Finder, the restriction on locations and filters will however be lost in the process.

HoudahSpot has a concept of "Templates" that you can use to much of the same effect as "Smart Folders".

**Full disclosure: HoudahSpot is a commercial product of which I am the developer.**

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173291/how-exclude-a-specific-folder-from-spotlight-search-but-not-from-search-window/173488#173488 This answer clearly says that path based file exclusion can be done. Then how is your first statement correct ?

Comment: The answer at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173291/how-exclude-a-specific-folder-from-spotlight-search-but-not-from-search-window/173488#173488 explains how to exclude folders from Spotlight indexing. This does indeed prevent files from that folder from appearing in search results. Since the folder is no longer indexed, its contents will however not appear in any search. This is not desirable.

Comment: The answer at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173291/how-exclude-a-specific-folder-from-spotlight-search-but-not-from-search-window/173488#173488 also suggests that the Finder may be able to perform searches without using the Spotlight index. Such searches can only find files by file system attributes like name. Never by content.

Comment: @ankii I believe I finally understand the reason for the confusion / misunderstanding. By "Spotlight does not know / care about file paths" I mean that the file path is not an indexed property.

As per the other answer, one can exclude folders from Spotlight indexing. In that sense Spotlight does care about file paths. It knows where it is allowed to go: which files and folders to process.

Comment: yes, the wording is a bit off.. if you correct it, I'll remove my downvote

Comment: I don’t get the down votes here _at all_ - very expert guidance, by the way the product I work on knows a bit about searching, self disclosed. Thanks for the post Pierre +1 from me for certain