Spotlight searches: exclude iCloud
On my MPB running Sonoma with "Search: This Mac "Documents"" duly displayed, all my Spotlight search results come solely from my iCloud backup.
Is there a way to force Spotlight to only return results from my hard disk rather than the iCloud?

Documents is also on your disk, thus valid for Spotlight indexing, and if switched on is mirrored to iCloud. iCloud is not a backup. Can you clarify and edit your question please?

If you turn off the Desktop and Documents sync, please make sure to move all your data somewhere else before toggling the option.  If you don't, it will appear that your data has disappeared.  It hasn't, it's still in the iCloud folder, you just can't see it.

Noam: Many thanks. That looks like the information I was looking for. I'll report back after seeing how it works.

Like this, you want to tell spotlight to search a folder that’s different than all files? https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/173488/5472 or do you want a different app that has this feature?

You can try System Setting -> Spotlight -> Search Privacy...
There, you can add folders to be excluded from the Spotlight search.
